# Converting string to double, rounding value

Tags: c#, ms-access, double

I'm converting string value to double and sending it to database. Displaying 6 decimal places.
Here is the code

```
strUpdate = "UPDATE tbPrice SET dblPrice = " 
    + Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text.Trim())
    + ",chrCity  = '" + txCity.Text.Trim()
    + "' WHERE pk_lngID = " + txtID.Text.Trim();
```

Here `txtPrice` value is `1.23456789`, but when it is updated into database its value changed to `1.2345679`. why is it rounding off the value. I need to get `1.234567` (user entered value truncated upto 6 decimal places.

Comment: What kind of db?  And what is the column type set to?

Comment: It is access, column was set to double. Actually sending textbox value to database column which is double.

Comment: okay, in Access, you can set your field type to Number. then set the number of decimal places for what you want. If you use less than say, 6, it will round the number to the 5th.

Comment: As per the design document i should go with only double. I want to display 6 decimal places and wrote code for that. but still didn't get why it is rounding off. Is that how C# conversion works or what. thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the DB is causing the rounding, not your C#.  I don't there there IS a way to set a specific type "double" in Access.  I have it open in the background here, and "Number" with options is the only thing there.

Comment: under column, there is general tab, where you can set it as double and  decimal places too under it. Rounding happening in the DB? Is there anyway to take that off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing my comments as they ended up being the accepted answer:

okay, in Access, you can set your field type to Number. then set the number of decimal places for what you want. If you use less than say, 6, it will round the number to the 5th.

I think the DB is causing the rounding, not your C#. I don't there there IS a way to set a specific type "double" in Access. Edit:  Double is there, but the bottom line is the number of decimal places need to be set correctly.

Please see comments for full conversation.